# PulseAudio on Debian 9: How to adjust default sound volume level?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, volume

Every time I boot up my Debian machine the sound volume level is at 100 % (what is way too loud). I am using `PulseAudio` instead of `Alsa`.

---

How can I adjust the default sound volume level to an arbitrary value (e.g. 30 %)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 30%
```

command as autostart.

The other way:

```
echo 'set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 20000' >> ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `echo 'set-sink-volume 0 30%' >> ~/.config/pulse/default.pa` - will this preserve my new settings temporarily or durable as well (independent of reboots)?

Comment: updated - don't use percentage in default.pa, only in commandline.

Comment: Attention: The second command does NOT work. `PulseAudio` will throw an error when rebooting the machine "PulseAudio can not connect blablabla"...

Comment: It works for me with pulseaudio **12.2**.

Answer (score 0):

copy Pulseaudio configuration file to home folder

```
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

add this line to disable Pulseaudio reset audio level to 100%

```
echo 'flat-volumes = no' >> ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

restart Pulseaudio/log out/restart pc to load new settings